# How to sub total more than 1 in dynamic pivot sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to create a query with a total and 2 sub total from 2 coulin in dynamic pivot.

i have table & query like this

[image]

```js
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
(
    Class varchar(10),
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(10),
    Item varchar(10),
    temp varchar (10)
)

INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES
('abc', 'Ron', 'A', 'Pencil', '12345'),
('abc', 'Ron', 'A', 'Pen', '2345'),
('abc', 'Tom', 'C', 'Pencil', '34343'),
('abc', 'Tom', 'D', 'Pencil', '252525'),
('def', 'Ron', 'E', 'Pen', '35345'),
('def', 'Tom', 'F', 'Pencil', '87878'),
('def', 'Tom', 'G', 'Pen', '9876'),
('ghi', 'Ron', 'H', 'Pen', '09090'),
('ghi', 'Ron', 'I', 'Pen', '40404'),
('ghi', 'Tom', 'J', 'Pencil', '144442345'),
('ghi', 'Tom', 'K', 'Pencil', '4444333')


DECLARE @Pivot_Columns  AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @select_Columns VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Pivot_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SELECT @select_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Sum(' + Quotename(item) + ') as '+Quotename(item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 0 then ''Total''+ '' '' + class 
when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 1 then ''Total'' 
else class end class, name, location, temp,'
           + @select_Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT class, name, location, item, temp
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ('
           + @Pivot_Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
group by class, name, location, temp with rollup 
'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

And how to create data like this?
[image]

I just wanna show subtotal from name based on class& subtotal class, but in my first imager there is sub total based on temp. If i change 'group by class, name with rollup' there's show error..

Appreciate any help, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this (I just reviewed first case, added a CASE for name and added HAVING conditions):

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT 
                    case when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 0 then ''TOTAL ''+ '' '' + class  
                        when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 1 then ''TOTAL ''                     
                        else class end class
            ,  case when grouping(location)=1 AND grouping(temp)=1 THEN ''TOTAL ''+name
                        else name end name, location, temp,'
           + @select_Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT class, name, location, item, temp
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ('
           + @Pivot_Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
group by class, name, location, temp with ROLLUP 
HAVING (grouping(location)=1 AND grouping(temp)=1 ) OR (grouping(location)=0 AND grouping(temp)=0 AND grouping(name)=0 AND grouping(class)=0)
'
```

**Update:**

You can use GROUPING SETS, obtaining same result (avoid using HAVING condition in my former query):

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT 
                    case when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 0 then ''TOTAL ''+ '' '' + class  
                        when grouping(name) = 1 and grouping(class) = 1 then ''TOTAL ''                     
                        else class end class
            ,  case when grouping(location)=1 AND grouping(temp)=1 THEN ''TOTAL ''+name
                        else name end name, location, temp,'
           + @select_Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT class, name, location, item, temp
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ('
           + @Pivot_Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
group by GROUPING SETS ((class,name), (class), (class, name, location, temp),())

'
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+--------+
|   class    |   name    | location |   temp    | Pen | Pencil |
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+--------+
| abc        | Ron       | A        | 12345     |   0 |      1 |
| abc        | Ron       | A        | 2345      |   1 |      0 |
| abc        | TOTAL Ron | NULL     | NULL      |   1 |      1 |
| abc        | Tom       | C        | 34343     |   0 |      1 |
| abc        | Tom       | D        | 252525    |   0 |      1 |
| abc        | TOTAL Tom | NULL     | NULL      |   0 |      2 |
| TOTAL  abc | NULL      | NULL     | NULL      |   1 |      3 |
| def        | Ron       | E        | 35345     |   1 |      0 |
| def        | TOTAL Ron | NULL     | NULL      |   1 |      0 |
| def        | Tom       | F        | 87878     |   0 |      1 |
| def        | Tom       | G        | 9876      |   1 |      0 |
| def        | TOTAL Tom | NULL     | NULL      |   1 |      1 |
| TOTAL  def | NULL      | NULL     | NULL      |   2 |      1 |
| ghi        | Ron       | H        | 09090     |   1 |      0 |
| ghi        | Ron       | I        | 40404     |   1 |      0 |
| ghi        | TOTAL Ron | NULL     | NULL      |   2 |      0 |
| ghi        | Tom       | J        | 144442345 |   0 |      1 |
| ghi        | Tom       | K        | 4444333   |   0 |      1 |
| ghi        | TOTAL Tom | NULL     | NULL      |   0 |      2 |
| TOTAL  ghi | NULL      | NULL     | NULL      |   2 |      2 |
| TOTAL      | NULL      | NULL     | NULL      |   5 |      6 |
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: I already try GROUPING SETS but my query not working well.. 
and your query worked fine thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may find **[this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7db49578-a1ef-4e53-864b-c61c5e1150f7/how-do-i-aggregate-on-more-than-one-column-within-a-pivot?forum=transactsql)** is helpful.

Or, here is another solution:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Code = '01' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS Value1_01  
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Code = '02' THEN Value1 ELSE 0 END) AS Value1_02  
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Code = '01' THEN Value2  ELSE 0 END) AS Value2_01  
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Code = '02' THEN Value2  ELSE 0 END) AS Value2_02  
FROM TableName
```